# Why Associations are Magnitudes in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

I haven't checked many dialects yet (in Pharo `Association` is a subclass of `LookupKey`, which is a subclass of `Magnitude`) but I presume this is fairly common.

Isn't this definition counterintuitive? `Associations` usually take part in unordered collections and I don't think a Smalltalker ever takes into account that their `keys` could be sent `#<=`. What I would like to know is whether this is something we inherited from old implementations of Smalltalk and never bothered to challenge, or it is just me who am missing something. Bottomline: has anyone ever used this feature?

Comment: Interesting question. GNU Smalltalk has the same structure and I hadn't noticed it before. I've used the `Association` objects before but not taken advantage of their heritage as a `Magnitude`. Perhaps the `Magnitude`-ness of `Association` is used internally in other objects (such as `Dictionary`), but I haven't looked at the source to verify that. That's about all I know at this time.

Comment: This hierarchy was already in st80 for sure.

Comment: @aka.nice In an admittedly quick search, I couldn't find anything about this decision in the Blue Book.

Comment: The hierarchy is shown this way in the Blue Book as well, but as you say, it doesn't explain why the LookupKey is a Magnitude. Under the Magnitude discussion, it says, *`LookupKey` is less interesting and is deferred until needed in the chapter on collections.*, which made me chuckle. The Collections section only refers to equality as the check done with keys. No other comparative operations are mentioned. I skimmed the source code in GNU Smalltalk and couldn't find any relative magnitude checks on a LookupKey or Association directly.

Comment: I would expect keys to be sortable. In another language (Delphi) I created collection types using that to create a very fast and memory-efficient storage system.

Comment: @StephanEggermont Thanks for the comment. Is there any place where I could learn more about your system?

Comment: I can definitely see the utility of having the key (`LookupKey` in this case) be a Magnitude.Further to that, it's interesting that `Association` is a subclass of `LookupKey` rather than an independent class that just *uses* a `LookupKey`. So that means `Association` objects can be compared directly as magnitudes, which, by default, compares by key.

Comment: @Leandro that was a custom system 10 years ago, data warehouse engine with a web frontend. Fully ram-based. 1 GB of fully normalised data, about 8 million registrations. Slices through the n-cube within 1.5 s on a 3GHz Pentium 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Dictionary needs that; all it needs are = and hash.

However, you often want to get a list of associations and sort them later (eg. to show them in some sorted list). Then, it is nice to have an order defined already.

And the cost is only a "<" method in Association (or LookupKey, if that is the superclass), so it comes almost for free by inheriting from Magnitude instead of Object.